# Header align center irrespective of device width in css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am stuck with a css problem where i need to align my header to center irrespective to the device width, i.e for any device the header should appear in center.
Here i am providing the css that is already applied.

```css
ul.nav.nav-tabs{
     display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    ul.nav.nav-tabs li{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        white-space: wrap;
    }
    ul.nav.nav-tabs li:last-child:after{
        content: "";
        background: url("");
    }
    ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active:after {
        background: url(../images/right-chevron-orange.png) center right -3px no-repeat;
        background-size: 16px;
    }
    ul.nav.nav-tabs li:after{
        content: "";
        background: url(../images/right-chevron.png) center right -3px no-repeat;
        width: 20px;
        background-size: 16px;
        position: absolute;
        height: 20px;
        right: 6px;
        top: 18px;
    }
    .nav-tabs>li{
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ng-scope" id="navigation-tabs" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
      <li class="increase_min_width active" ng-class="{active : navPath == 'basic'}">
        <div class="wrap">
          <span class="circle">1</span>
          <a style="text-decoration:none;">Basic Information</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="increase_min_width disabled" ng-class="{active : navPath == 'company',disabled:moveToCompanyFlg ==''}">
        <div class="wrap">
          <span class="circle">2</span>
          <a style="text-decoration:none;" class="company_information">Company Information</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{active : navPath == 'owner',disabled:moveToOwnerFlg ==''}" class="disabled">
        <div class="wrap">
          <span class="circle">3</span>
          <a style="text-decoration:none;">Owners Info</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I have tried setting margin:0 auto; and width:100%  for ul.nav.nav-tabs but it doesn't work. I have not much knowledge in css. 
Please help me with this... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please add images absolute path in your css of your question. To get idea of design you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flexbox css is incomplete

Add a `justify-content: center;` to your `.nav-tabs`

Answer (score 2):

Add `justify-content:center;` to ul class `.nav-tabs`

Check this pen

```
`https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odRMWV`
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content: center;` in the `ul.nav.nav-tabs` CSS

```css
ul.nav.nav-tabs{
     display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
        
    }
    
    ul.nav.nav-tabs li{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        white-space: wrap;
    }
    ul.nav.nav-tabs li:last-child:after{
        content: "";
        background: url("");
    }
    ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active:after {
        background: url(../images/right-chevron-orange.png) center right -3px no-repeat;
        background-size: 16px;
    }
    ul.nav.nav-tabs li:after{
        content: "";
        background: url(../images/right-chevron.png) center right -3px no-repeat;
        width: 20px;
        background-size: 16px;
        position: absolute;
        height: 20px;
        right: 6px;
        top: 18px;
    }
    .nav-tabs>li{
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ng-scope" id="navigation-tabs" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
      <li class="increase_min_width active" ng-class="{active : navPath == 'basic'}">
        <div class="wrap">
          <span class="circle">1</span>
          <a style="text-decoration:none;">Basic Information</a>
        </div>
      </li><br>
      <li class="increase_min_width disabled" ng-class="{active : navPath == 'company',disabled:moveToCompanyFlg ==''}">
        <div class="wrap">
          <span class="circle">2</span>
          <a style="text-decoration:none;" class="company_information">Company Information</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{active : navPath == 'owner',disabled:moveToOwnerFlg ==''}" class="disabled">
        <div class="wrap">
          <span class="circle">3</span>
          <a style="text-decoration:none;">Owners Info</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```